# Update a JProgressBar while Downloading a File

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I am trying to create a installer, that is downloading some files for my program. While a file is downloading I want my JProgressBar to be updated, but somehow the program is freezing when I use my code.

*My download void*

```
    public static boolean download() {
    URL url = null;
    try {
         url = new URL("http://(domainnameremoved).de/download/1408/");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final Download download = new Download(url);
    Start.progressBar.setMinimum(0);
    Start.progressBar.setMaximum(download.getSize());

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(!(download.getStatus() == 2)||!(download.getStatus() == 3)||!(download.getStatus() == 4)) {
                Start.progressBar.setValue(download.getDownloaded());
            }
            }

    });

    if(download.getStatus() == 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }


}
```

My download class (not from me, I found it on the internet)

```
public class Download extends Observable implements Runnable {

// Max size of download buffer.
private static final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

// These are the status names.
public static final String STATUSES[] = {"Downloading",
"Paused", "Complete", "Cancelled", "Error"};

// These are the status codes.
public static final int DOWNLOADING = 0;
public static final int PAUSED = 1;
public static final int COMPLETE = 2;
public static final int CANCELLED = 3;
public static final int ERROR = 4;

private URL url; // download URL
private int size; // size of download in bytes
private int downloaded; // number of bytes downloaded
private int status; // current status of download

// Constructor for Download.
public Download(URL url) {
    this.url = url;
    size = -1;
    downloaded = 0;
    status = DOWNLOADING;

    // Begin the download.
    download();
}

// Get this download's URL.
public String getUrl() {
    return url.toString();
}

public int getDownloaded() {
    return this.downloaded;
}

// Get this download's size.
public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

// Get this download's progress.
public float getProgress() {
    return ((float) downloaded / size) * 100;
}

// Get this download's status.
public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

// Pause this download.
public void pause() {
    status = PAUSED;
    stateChanged();
}

// Resume this download.
public void resume() {
    status = DOWNLOADING;
    stateChanged();
    download();
}

// Cancel this download.
public void cancel() {
    status = CANCELLED;
    stateChanged();
}

// Mark this download as having an error.
private void error() {
    status = ERROR;
    stateChanged();
}

// Start or resume downloading.
private void download() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

// Get file name portion of URL.
private String getFileName(URL url) {
    String fileName = url.getFile();
    return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
}

// Download file.
public void run() {
    RandomAccessFile file = null;
    InputStream stream = null;

    try {
        // Open connection to URL.
        HttpURLConnection connection =
                (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Specify what portion of file to download.
        connection.setRequestProperty("Range",
                "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");

        // Connect to server.
        connection.connect();

        // Make sure response code is in the 200 range.
        if (connection.getResponseCode() / 100 != 2) {
            error();
        }

        // Check for valid content length.
        int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
        if (contentLength < 1) {
            error();
        }

  /* Set the size for this download if it
     hasn't been already set. */
        if (size == -1) {
            size = contentLength;
            stateChanged();
        }

        // Open file and seek to the end of it.
        file = new RandomAccessFile(getFileName(url), "rw");
        file.seek(downloaded);

        stream = connection.getInputStream();
        while (status == DOWNLOADING) {
    /* Size buffer according to how much of the
       file is left to download. */
            byte buffer[];
            if (size - downloaded > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            } else {
                buffer = new byte[size - downloaded];
            }

            // Read from server into buffer.
            int read = stream.read(buffer);
            if (read == -1)
                break;

            // Write buffer to file.
            file.write(buffer, 0, read);
            downloaded += read;
            stateChanged();
        }

  /* Change status to complete if this point was
     reached because downloading has finished. */
        if (status == DOWNLOADING) {
            status = COMPLETE;
            stateChanged();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error();
    } finally {
        // Close file.
        if (file != null) {
            try {
                file.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        // Close connection to server.
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}

// Notify observers that this download's status has changed.
private void stateChanged() {
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
}
```

Do you know why my program is just freezing and why my ProgressBar doesn't update?

Comment: Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).  `invokeLater` isn't doing what you think it is

Comment: And have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020949/jprogressbar-isnt-progressing/12021971#12021971) for some ideas

Answer (score 0):

There could be issue if you use some custom Look&Feel which is not thread safe. If you use default Look&Feel this could't happen. 
Possible issue in your case it that when a some URL socket is open that blocks main thread. You invoks SwingUtilities.invokeLater... to update progressbar, this SwingUtils.invokLater() will wait until that web socket is closed. You could use simple:

```
      new Thread(new Runnable(){ public void run(){ do here what you want in your case...}}).start();
```

or you colud use more complicated SwingWorker object. Also
you may use Thread.sleep() method with value of ~1 to 5ms into both run() methods into Download class and download method to optimize processor stress.