# jLabel not changing text and jProgressbar not updating

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I have a `JFrame`. in the `JFrame` is a `JDesktopPane`, `JComboBox`, several `JLabel`s, and a `JProgressBar`. I am facing two challenges:

1. I want to update/change the text in one of the `JLabel`s in the `JFrame` by clicking a `JButton` that is on a `JInternalFrame` (the button does some calculations).
2. Upon clicking a `JButton` that is on another `JInternalFrame` (the button performs a small task), I want to use the `JProgressBar` (progressbar is in `JFrame`) to show the progress of work done.

I use `SwingUtilities.invokelater()` to perform the tasks done by the buttons.
am using NetBeans as my IDE.

Comment: Could you share what you've already tried (code)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], and go through the [help] and learn [ask], then post a valid [mcve] or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/). If your problem is related to you wanting to change the text from a `JLabel` on button click, then create a simple window with a `JLabel` and a `JButton` and on its `actionPerformed` call `myLabel.setText("Whatever text you want");`. Also please write some capitalized words when needed, it's hard to read everything in lower case.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020949/jprogressbar-isnt-progressing/12021971#12021971)

Comment: thanks to you all for the swift response. every other parts of the program is working fine its just the jLabel and jProgressBar that is giving me issue. what i observe was the "new text" that should be display by the jLabel is not showing but when i do print on the jLabel, it shows the new text.

Comment: when i want to access any variable in the jFrame from the jInternalFrame, i create a new instance of the jFrame. class name of the jframe is home, so i do " home home1 = new home(); then (jLabel7 is public here) home1.jLabel7.setText("new text") but its not working. i even wrote a method named "AMOUNT" in the jFrame to get the new text then set it as the value of the jLabel. still not updating the jLabel . i even put theAMOUNT() method in the DONE method of a swingworker still not updating the jLabel.

Comment: please help and you can ask anything about the code. i should have post it but its much and i dont know which part to post. am using netbeans as my IDE. thanks once again

Comment: @hybee try to write a short example, like deleting everything not needed but still/just showing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know what is happening without code, but probably the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) is being blocked (or terminated?), e.g. by code being called by `invokeLater`. The EDT is used to update the GUI and should not be used for (slow) non-GUI related calculations. See tutorial The Event Dispatch Thread and subsequent for more details.

Example (without blocking):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelProgress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LabelProgress main = new LabelProgress();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> main.showInternal1());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> main.showInternal2());
    }

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private JDesktopPane desktop;
    private JProgressBar bar;

    private int progress = 0;

    private LabelProgress() {
        label = new JLabel("Label: ");

        desktop = new JDesktopPane();

        bar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        bar.setStringPainted(true);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        frame.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(bar, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.validate();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showInternal1() {
        JButton change = new JButton("Change");
        change.addActionListener(this::doChange);

        JInternalFrame internal = new JInternalFrame("Change Label");
        internal.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        internal.add(change);
        internal.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 150);
        internal.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(internal);
    }

    private void showInternal2() {
        JButton task = new JButton("Task");
        task.addActionListener(this::doTask);

        JInternalFrame internal = new JInternalFrame("Small Task");
        internal.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        internal.add(task);
        internal.setBounds(150, 100, 200, 150);
        internal.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(internal);
    }

    private void doChange(ActionEvent ev) {
        // using a SwingWorker:
        // for demonstration I used an anonymous class, maybe a own class is better
        SwingWorker<LocalTime , Void> worker = new SwingWorker<LocalTime , Void>() {
            @Override
            protected LocalTime doInBackground() throws Exception {
                // not executed on the EDT - just get the current time
                LocalTime someCalculation = LocalTime.now();
                return someCalculation;
            }
            @Override
            protected void done() {
                // executed on EDT
                try {
                    LocalTime resultOfSomeCalculation = get();
                    label.setText("Label: " + resultOfSomeCalculation.toString());

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }

    private void doTask(ActionEvent ev) {
        // no need to use SwingWorker
        Thread thread = new Thread(this::slowTask);
        thread.start();
    }

    private void slowTask() {
        // not really that slow, just for demonstration
        progress += 10;
        if (progress > 100) progress = 100;

        // and now switching to the EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> bar.setValue(progress));
    }
}
```