# Update a JProgressBar when JButton1 is activated

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I want to update `JProgressBar` when `jButton1` is activated, but it does not change until the `FunctionX()` is completed.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jProgressBar1.setValue(10);
    jProgressBar1.setValue(20);
    FunctionX();
}
```

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html), will show you how to use a JProgressBar.

Comment: [JProgressBar isn't progressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020949/jprogressbar-isnt-progressing/12021971#12021971).  Generally, I'd use a `SwingWorker` as it has a number of useful features which make this, otherwise complex problem, somewhat eaiser

Comment: Don't tag the IDE, it is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Does `FunctionX()` preform a long process ? (BTW following java naming conventions it should be `functionX()`)